# Barebones network appliance, 4+ GbE NICs, Intel chipset

Tags: networking, pfsense, hardware

Looking for a stepped-up ALIX or Soekris embedded network appliance to load pfSense and/or handle other FOSS-based network roles.

Main criteria is a GbE NICs (will be used for core routing/firewalling with managed GbE switches), DDR3 RAM capable, and multi-core/Intel Atom processor, in a 1U rack-mountable case or smaller.

[Axiomtek](http://axiomtek.com/products/ViewProduct.asp?ptype3=232&pos=2&ptype2=231&ptype1=209) has the ideal product but I don't think they have retail channels.

Comment: For multiple GbE NICs, how many? If you could install a single quad-port PCI-e would that be enough? Or do you need 4 individual NICs?

Comment: I think that would ok, although I'm a bit skeptical about throughput on the quad cards (skeptical, perhaps without justification though, as I haven't tried it) vs. a dedicated backplane for 4 NICs.

Comment: If a 10Gbps NIC can be fed over PCIe then a quad-1Gbps NIC can.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping]http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own around [this Supermicro chassis](http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/1U/502/SC502-200.cfm).  But you would need to use the 4 port Intel NIC to accomplish your goal.

Comment: i think this is the best route: build my own.  While I've uncovered a pile of pre-built options, there's always a component that's lacking or I don't need/want.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following as a reference for anyone else who stumbles upon this question:

Netgate Hamakua 1U (or DT):
http://store.netgate.com/Netgate-Hamakua-1U-P229C61.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Supermicro provides Atom solution, such as [this one](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/5015/SYS-5015A-EHF-D525.cfm), together with one PCIe x4 gigabit LAN card maybe suits you.